# Check if String in String[] is in ArrayList<string>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, arrays

I just built a Broadcast Receiver with which I can get the incoming text messages, than I split the text message when there's a space and save it into a `String[]`.

Now I need to check if in this `String[]` is something from my database. For that I created a `ArrayList<String>`, which gets all the entries from the corresponding column. Now I need to check if a String in my `ArrayList` is the same in my `String[]` from the text message, but I don't know how to realize that.

Is there an easy and fast way to check that, also I need to know which String is in both of them?

**SmileySmsReceiver:**

```
  package de.retowaelchli.filterit.services;


    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.SFilterDBAdapter;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class SmileySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            //Datenbank definieren
            SFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper = new SFilterDBAdapter(context);


            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Log.d("SmileySmsReceiver", "Yes it calls the onReceive");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                Log.d("SmileySmsReceiver", "Bundle is not null");
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";        
                Log.d("SmileySmsReceiver","Was steht in der Nachricht?: " + str);

                String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");

                //Hier werden die Strings der Smileys aus der Datenbank gezogen
                mDbHelper.open();
                Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllSFilter();

                ArrayList<String> SmileyList = new ArrayList<String>();
                c.getColumnIndex(SFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD);
                int ColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(SFilterDBAdapter.KEYWORD);
                    if(c!=null)
                        {
                        //Hier werden die Smileys in die ArrayList geschrieben
                        while(c.moveToNext()){
                            String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );
                            SmileyList.add(infoItem);
                        }
<------------------------- FROM HERE ON I NEED YOUR GUYS HELP ------------------------------->
                }
                }
                //---display the new SMS message---
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }                         
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we assign values directly to List from split function??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a `String myString` and an `ArrayList<String> myListOfStrings`, you can check if `myString` is in the list like this:

```
myListOfStrings.contains( myString );
```

This will return a boolean (true/false) - true if the strings was found, false if not.

In your case you would want to run through the array of strings and match each of them to the `SmileyList` like this:

```
for( String s : splitted ) {
   if( SmileyList.contains( s ) ) {
     //Do what you need to do if the string is in the SmileyList.
   }
}
```

Comment: thx for you awnser, but how I find out now, which String was in both of them?

Comment: If `if( SmileyList.contains( s ) )` returns `true`, the string that was in both is equal to `s`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Do you need the index/position of `s` in the original String? Do you need the value of `s`? Do you need the index of `s` in `splitted`?

Comment: the value of s, do i need, i think. I need to know what String is in the ArrayList and the String[]... got it?

Comment: Okay - I'll try to explain more in depth. We run through the strings in the array `splitted` one by one, creating a reference `s` to the one we're currently working with. We then "ask" the `ArrayList SmileyList` if it contains a string that is equal to `s`. If it does we know that `s` which we got form `splitted` (this means it is in `splitted`) is also in `SmileyList` meaning it is in both. The `String` which is in both the `ArrayList` and the `String[]` is `s`. We then do what needs to be done in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

```
String array[] = ... ; 
List<String> list = ... ;
// check if anything in array is in list
for(String str : array)
    if(list.contains(str)) doSomething() ;
```

If you want do something for every match, the code above will work. If you only want to do something once if there was a match (and not for every match), you will need to add a `break` statement in the if sentence.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the array (e.g. with a `for` loop over `splitted.length`), querying your list with `myList.contains(splitted[i])`. The query will return a `boolean`.

If you need to check if **all** items in the array are present in the List, there is a comfortable alternative with `myList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(splitted))`

There is another concise alternative without looping to check if **any** item of the array is present in the list :

```
List splitList = Arrays.asList(splitted);
splitList.retainAll(myList);
```

`splitList.isEmpty()` will then return `false`, if **any item** of the lists is matching.

The contents of the `splitList` will show all strings that have matched.

Comment: It might be positive to add an exit condition to the loop for efficiency. The OP only wants to know if at least one element is contained in the list.

Comment: definitely, it would be positive to break the loop once you have the answer - I simply considered control flow outside the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large your array and ArrayList are and how many times you will access them, you might want to use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList so that you can get a fast look up with the hashed `contains()` method instead of having to iterate through the ArrayList. Something like this:

```
boolean containsString(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList, String[] stringArray) {
    Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>(stringArrayList); // if same input is used reused, might want this outside the method

    for (String s : stringArray) {
        if (stringSet.contains(s)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```